# Get number of tasks in a named queue?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a named task queue. Is there a way to get the # of tasks it currently contains, from the java API?

I know I can check the console page for it, but I'd like to get the count via code so I can report back to the user how many tasks are in there so they know how long they'll have to wait roughly before their task is going to get serviced.

Thanks

Comment: Something like this? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueStatistics.html#getNumTasks--

Comment: Oh yeah that's it, sorry i didn't see it linked in the docs on the task queues. Can you make this an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various stats about a queue are available in the [Class QueueStatistics](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueStatistics#class-queuestatistics)

Easy to miss note important in *some* cases (probably not in yours, as you just want to provide an ETA, which doesn't have to be 100% precise) (emphasis mine):

> QueueStatistics allow observation of the rate that tasks on a given
>   queue are being executed. **Note that statistics provided are only
>   approximate, and some statistics may be delayed or transiently
>   unavailable**.

The method that seems to be what you're looking after is [getNumTasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueStatistics.html#getNumTasks--):

> ```
> getNumTasks
>
> public int getNumTasks()
>
> Returns:
>     The approximate number of non-completed tasks in the queue.
> ```